# CounterClass cannot be resolved

Tags: android, eclipse

This might be a very simple question but I can't seem to find the answer so any help would be appreciated.

I'm trying to run android app but there is an error in the code. I found the code in Internet and it should work properly but not in my case. In the code there is a line

```
final CounterClass timer = new CounterClass(180000,1000);
```

where CounterClass is underlined and there is an error message that CounterClass cannot be resolved to a type.

What should I do to get rid of the error?

```
package com.manish.timer;  
 import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;  
 import android.annotation.SuppressLint;  
 import android.annotation.TargetApi;  
 import android.app.Activity;  
 import android.os.Build;  
 import android.os.Bundle;  
 import android.os.CountDownTimer;  
 import android.view.View;  
 import android.view.View.OnClickListener;  
 import android.widget.Button;  
 import android.widget.TextView;  
 @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)  
 @SuppressLint("NewApi")  
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {  
      Button btnStart, btnStop;  
      TextView textViewTime;  
      @Override  
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  
          btnStart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStart);  
          btnStop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStop);  
          textViewTime = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewTime);  
          textViewTime.setText("00:03:00");   
          final CounterClass timer = new CounterClass(180000,1000);  
          btnStart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
            @Override  
            public void onClick(View v) {  
              timer.start();  
            }  
          });  
          btnStop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
            @Override  
            public void onClick(View v) {  
              timer.cancel();  
            }  
          });  
        }  
      @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)  
      @SuppressLint("NewApi")  
      public class CounterClass extends CountDownTimer {  
           public CounterClass(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {  
                super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);  
           }  
           @Override  
          public void onFinish() {  
            textViewTime.setText("Completed.");  
          }  
           @SuppressLint("NewApi")  
           @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)  
           @Override  
           public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {  
                 long millis = millisUntilFinished;  
                  String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis),  
                      TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)),  
                      TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));  
                  System.out.println(hms);  
                  textViewTime.setText(hms);  
           }  
      }  
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Inner classes have to be instanciated in a special way.  The syntax is:

```
OuterClass.InnerClass innerObject = outerObject.new InnerClass();
```

So in your case, it should be:

```
final MainActivity.CounterClass timer = this.new CounterClass(180000,1000);
```

Comment: Casey, thank You for answering!

Unfortunately it didn't resolve my problem because MainActivity.CounterClass is still underlined and there is the same message: MainActivity.CounterClass cannot be resolved to a type.